# SelectedIndexChanged DDL in JQuery Lightbox

Tags: asp.net, .net, c#-4.0

I have a div on my aspx page that is hidden(using display:none css). When a user clicks a button a lightbox shows up that has a dropdownlist on it. When they select something it doesn't fire the selectedindexchanged event.

For testing purposes, it works just fine when I set the style to display:block and select the dropdown list outside of the pop up window(lightbox)

http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPlan" AppendDataBoundItems="true" AutoPostBack="True" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlPlan_SelectedIndexChanged" EnableViewState="True"
```

The control isn't binding on postback, I'm using Page.IsPostBack and else on page load.

Thanks!

```
 <a class="meds" style="padding:0;" href="#"><img border="0" src="Images/Medications.jpg" alt="" style="margin-left:4px;margin-top:1px;"/></a>
<div id="medications" style="display:none;background-color:#EFEEEF;padding-left:15px;">
        <div style="width:100%;height:106px;background-image:url('Images/warning-bg.jpg');background-repeat:repeat-x;">
        <img src="Images/checkoutItems.jpg" />
    </div>
<div style="padding-left:15px;">
    <p>Select a plan in the dropdown list below, and you will see suggested visit items for the package. If the patient isn't using a package for this visit, then check "Charge Item", and the totals will be calculated.</p>
    <div><asp:Label ID="Label" runat="server" Text="Select Plan " Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label><asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPlan" AppendDataBoundItems="true" AutoPostBack="True" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlPlan_SelectedIndexChanged" EnableViewState="True">
                    <asp:ListItem> </asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
</div>
</div>
```

In the head I have:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
                    $("a.meds").colorbox({
                    width: "50%", height: "84%", inline: true, href: function () {
                        // var elementID = $(this).attr('id');
                        return "#medications";
                    }, onOpen: function () { $('#medications').show(); }, onCleanup: function () { $('#medications').hide(); }

                }); 
      });
```

Code behind on page load:

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {

                ddlPlan.Items.Clear();
                ddlPlan.DataSource = Database.GetAllPlans();
                ddlPlan.DataBind();
                ddlPlan.Items.Insert(0, " ");
}
```

code behind selectedindexchanged:

```
protected void ddlPlan_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ddlPlan.SelectedIndex == 0)
    {
        txtTotal.Text = "";
        txtNetTotal.Text = "";
        ClearAll();
        return;
    }
```

Comment: Please, post your markup

Comment: if you use updatepanel than declare ddlPlan_SelectedIndexChanged in async event